# I want to run a function after an input field has been entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small form that currently uses a button to get the latitude and longitude from Google Maps API and puts the results into an input field. The trigger is a event listener on the button. I want to get rid of the button and after the city has been added trigger the event. I am not sure how this is accomplished.
Here is my code in JS fidler.  [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/z6874xou/2/)

```
function showResult(result) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = result.geometry.location.lat()   +' '+ result.geometry.location.lng();

}

function getLatitudeLongitude(callback, address) {
     // If adress is not supplied, use default value 'Ferrol, Galicia, Spain'
address = address || 'Ferrol, Galicia, Spain';
    // Initialize the Geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                callback(results[0]);
            }
        });
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('btn');

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var address = document.getElementById('street').value  +' '+ document.getElementById('city').value;
    getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address)
});
```

Comment: try google maps autocomplete places api.

Answer (score 0):

Fire the event on change of city.

```
var city = document.getElementById('city');

city.addEventListener("change", function () {
    var address = document.getElementById('street').value  +' '+ document.getElementById('city').value;
    getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

event on blur:

```
var city = document.getElementById('city');
city.addEventListener("blur", function () {
   var address = document.getElementById('street').value  +' '+ document.getElementById('city').value;
   getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address)
});
```

update fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6874xou/10/

Answer (score 0):

Check this code [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6874xou/11/).  I have added onchange event for city input box

```
 var city = document.getElementById('city');

 city.addEventListener("change", function () {
 var address = document.getElementById('street').value  +' '+ 
 document.getElementById('city').value;
 getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address) 
});
```